# Blank page on npm start react

Tags: reactjs, localhost, npm-start

I'm new to React and I'm creating a React app
which on npm start it's returning a blank page.
Below is :

Here's my index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import App from '../src/App';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, 
document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route 
} from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <div>
        Ecommerce  
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Open browser dev tools and see if there are any errors displayed in the console.

Comment: Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform  is the error I'm getting

Comment: You are not even using anything from `react-router-dom` so regardless of whether or not it's installed is irrelevant, other than you'd likely see some import errors. I don't see any issues in the code you've shared and see no reason why it wouldn't render the `div` element with "Ecommerce" text. Do you have any error messages in your console?

Comment: I managed to fix this. Was missing a few dependencies that were needed .

Comment: sometimes is cache, just re start pc

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have installed `react-router-dom`:

```
npm i react-router-dom
```

Comment: I have it installed already

Comment: That was all I had to do to get your code running on a fresh CRA project. Are you getting any errors in the browser console, and are you using any extensions that might interfere?

Comment: router is not a requirement to run react. sample app works just fine w/out it

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem until just now I turned off my VPN.

- Turn off VPN
- restart your app (npm start)
- let us know if it works

Comment: sometimes  is cache, re starting browser its works, that happend when u get the build

Comment: I was able to solve this by clearing my history, including cache, then restarting the app

Answer (score 0):

For me I didn't realize that another react project I had running was blocking this second project from starting.  So by stopping the first react project my second one started working.  Another solution would be to give the different projects different ports.  This may not be your exact problem but it may solve the title of this question for some people.